# How can you decode multiple message types with golang websockets?

Tags: websocket, go

I have a go program using the (relatively) standard [go.net/websocket‎](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket) library. I'm trying to receive and decode messages from a web page that have a different structure for each type of message, i.e.

```
{type: "messagetype", msg: { /* structure different for each message type */ } }
```

Is there any way to do a "partial" decode of the message, only checking the `type` field before proceeding to decode the actual message into a go struct?

Would this necessitate writing a custom `Codec`, a'la `JSON`, that delegates to the JSON codec for the message itself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [json.RawMessage](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) to delay the decoding, eg

```
struct {
    type string
    msg  json.RawMessage
}
```

`json.RawMessage` is an alias for `[]byte` which you can then further decode as you wish.

Comment: Thank you! I almost gave up, but I really hated the idea that I need to use reflection or try/catch different unmarshalings. This is so much better.