# Unmarshalling a JSON that may or may not return an array?

Tags: json, go

I'm retrieving JSON from a third party website (home electricity usage), and depending on what I've requested from the site, the JSON returned may or may not be an array. For example, if I request a list of my smart meters, I get this (results truncated, due to large size):

```
{"gwrcmds":{"gwrcmd":{"gcmd":"SPA_UserGetSmartMeterList","gdata":{"gip":{"version":"1"...
```

Where **gwrcmd** is a single element.

But if I request electricity usage for the last half hour, I get this:

```
{"gwrcmds":{"gwrcmd":[{"gcmd":"DeviceGetChart","gdata":{"gip":{"version":"1" ...
```

See how **gwrcmd** is now an array?

Within my Go app, I have a struct that looks like this (again, truncated, as it goes on for a while. There's more sub-structs and properties beneath "Version":

```
type Response struct {
    Gwrcmds struct {
        Gwrcmd struct {
            Gcmd  string
            Gdata struct {
                Gip struct {
                    Version string
```

If `gwrcmd` is an array, `Gwrcmd` needs to be a `[]struct { }`, but if it's not, it's just a regular old `struct { }`

The problem is that `json.Unmarshal` just returns an error if the JSON has an array and the struct does not have a slice (or vice versa).

Would I need to create a second struct that duplicates the first one (except with a `[]struct { }` instead), or is there a better way to do it? I thought of something with interfaces, but I haven't really touched those yet, so I'm not 100% sure on them.

Comment: One idea that pops to my head but seems sub-optimal is to implement an `io.Reader` which adds the `[` before a single `gcmd` structure and `]` at the end of it and then unmarshal from that reader.

Comment: In addition to the existing answers… you make request type A and get response type RA, you make request type B and get response type RB… perhaps you shouldn't try to read two different things (RA and RB) with the exact same code. It could be as simple as `type ResponseOne struct { Gwrcmdc struct { Gwrcmd GwCmdType } }` and `type ResponseMany struct { Gwrcmds struct { Gwrcmd []GwCmdType } }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, whenever you have a JSON value of unknown type, you will use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) to get it, peek into it, and unmarshal it correctly into the corresponding type. A simplified example:

```
// The A here can be either an object, or a JSON array of objects.
type Response struct {
    RawAWrapper struct {
        RawA json.RawMessage `json:"a"`
    }
    A  A   `json:"-"`
    As []A `json:"-"`
}

type A struct {
    B string
}

func (r *Response) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r.RawAWrapper); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if r.RawAWrapper.RawA[0] == '[' {
        return json.Unmarshal(r.RawAWrapper.RawA, &r.As)
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(r.RawAWrapper.RawA, &r.A)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/2d_OrGltDu.

Guessing the content based on the first byte doesn't seem too robust to me though. Usually you'll have some sort of a clue in your JSON (like a `length` or `type` field on the same level as the dynamic one) that tells you whether you have an object or an array.

See also:

- [How can you decode multiple message types with golang websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23053563/1892060)
- [Partly JSON unmarshal into a map in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066946/1892060)

Comment: Link to json.RawMessage documentation : https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage

Comment: @HectorJ wanted to add this, but forgot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to make custom json unmarshal method, like

```
func (a *GwrcmCustom) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    g, ga := Gwrcmd{}, []Gwrcmd{}
    if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &g); err == nil {
        *a = make([]Gwrcmd, 1)
        []Gwrcmd(*a)[0] = Gwrcmd(g)
        return
    }
    if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &ga); err == nil {
        *a = GwrcmCustom(ga)
        return
    }
    return
}
```

`GwrcmCustom` is a custom type, slice of `Gwrcm`

```
type GwrcmCustom []Gwrcmd
```

So we will get slice always

Try this on <kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A20Cnn-sC4)</kbd>

I hope this will help